# Importing Tab Delimited Text File with Multiline Cells (to Excel or Access)

Tags: excel, text-files, csv

The tab delimited text file that i am trying to import looks like this (4 fields, Field 3 is multiline)... and about 100,000 rows of data:

Below is just a sample... but please give a general solution where the multiline text could be in multiple fields... like say fld3, fld6 and fld7 of a total 10 fields.

```
Field 1 <tab> Field 2 <tab> Field 3.1
Field 3.2
Field 3.3<tab>Field 4
Field 1 <tab> Field 2 <tab> Field 3.1
Field 3.2
Field 3.3<tab>Field 4
Field 1 <tab> Field 2 <tab> Field 3.1
Field 3.2
Field 3.3<tab>Field 4
```

But, actually when it was was exported to the above text file from the database... it had 3 lines of actual... that looked like this... 4 Fields. **Field 3 is multiline.**

```
Field 1 <tab> Field 2 <tab> Field 3.1(CR)Field 3.2(CR)Field 3.3<tab>Field 4
Field 1 <tab> Field 2 <tab> Field 3.1(CR)Field 3.2(CR)Field 3.3<tab>Field 4
Field 1 <tab> Field 2 <tab> Field 3.1(CR)Field 3.2(CR)Field 3.3<tab>Field 4
```

where  is Tab, and (CR) is carriage return. When importing the tab delimited text file into Excel, i want all 3 lines in Field 3 (Field 3.1, Field 3.2 and Field 3.3) be in one cell, but multiline. So basically i want excel to ignore carriage return with in Field 3. How do i do that???

For your info... **The text fields are NOT in double quotes**... Please tell me what is the best way to convert the plain text tab delimited text file to Excel 4 columns like this:

[image: Excel File]

does anyone know of a solution. it would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Comment**

Please note that what I have is only the resulting Text File... as shown on the very top of this message.... with text "Field 3.2" in Line 2, "Field 3.3" and "Field 4" in Line 3 with  separating them.

Also... not necessarily Field 3 will be always multiline... it may be multiline with 2, 3 or more lines... or even nothing or single line. Field 3 will never have a  with in itself.

**Additional Comments with Sample File for someone to Test - Update 25Jun2013 09:05 UTC**

*pls note copy paste will not work.. as tabs are lost.. you will have to add it yourselves.*

File with Quotes around the multiline field:

```
f1hdr   f2hdr   f3hdr
f11 "f12
part of f12"    f13
f21 "f22part of f22
part f22
part f22
part f22"   f23
f31 "f32aaa"    f33
f41 "f42bbb"    f43
```

File without Quotes around the multiline field:

```
f1hdr   f2hdr   f3hdr
f11 f12
part of f12 f13
f21 f22part of f22
part f22
part f22
part f22    f23
f31 f32aaa  f33
f41 f42bbb  f43
```

Open the file with quotes in Excel... Open File Dialog... Hold Shift... and Click Open.. show the file nicely with multiline.

[image: capture 2 with quotes]

But opening the file without quotes.. doesn't work.. it breaks.

I have no idea why holding shift works. I knew of this from here: [Import multiline csv files into Excel internationally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443204/import-multiline-csv-files-into-excel-internationally?rq=1)

Now.. it still remains to be answered...

1) How to add the quotes around the text file in easier fashion before importing to Excel... Why Shift Open works? What if I want to control each delimited columns using text import wizard?

2) How to add the quotes around the fields by default in SQL Server 2015. This is in addition to above Q1. We still need a solution where we can't export the file again. But, for any new export.. someone could user the answer from Q2.

3) Any other methods which may be even simpler?

Comment: Can you fix the export? You really shouldn't have to deal with this to be honest. This export isn't valid for most systems. Where is this exporting from?

Comment: the export is from sql server 2015.. and the results are written to a file from there. i have seen few times where i get a quote around the whole field string. even then it is really a pain. You can suggest to me "how to do it properly export in sql server". But even then i still would like a reply for this question as it is so that where I can't fix the source... I need a way out to get the data cleaned like in the screenshot.... (to Excel or Access). Thank you for your time... i have been through your "about joseph" page just now on your site... good work there.

Comment: i see...hmmm...ok, I think I have an idea. And thanks for the feedback on my site :) i appreciate it

Comment: is there any way to tell when a row has terminated? for example, you have `field 3.3<tab>field 4`, will there always be a last column *without* a carriage return in it?

Comment: i guess my biggest concern is how would you know exactly where the row should end in the raw file? even looking at it manually? what if the last column has carriage returns?

Comment: If there are just CR in the data, what's the line-separator? CR+LF ?

Comment: You may have to pre or postprocess. But if it is not guaranteed that there are exactly 3 lines in the multiline column, and if the end of line is the same of the end of record, even with preprocess I can't see how this can be done

Comment: 3 <tab> means 4 fields... in the 4th field... there will be no multiline.. only single line that ends with CR... to close the row. if only way is to pre-process... I am sure it can be done.. 1st field is from start of line to 1st <tab>, 2nd field is from previous <tab> to next <tab>, 3rd field is from prev <tab> to next <tab> inclusive of the CR with in the data, 4th field is from the last <tab> to end of line. <tab> delimited in its literal sense... all fields are <tab> delimited... and just damn ignore what is in between the tabs and capture all the carriage returns as data with in the<tabs>

Comment: if pre-process is the only way... what is the best, easiest way to import the data into access or excel... without going round in circles.. preferably a click click click solution... no code involved. @TimWilliams Line Separator is CR as well.

Comment: Ok. I think the only way is writing a program in VBA to make the preprocess and the import. You must write code, I fear.

Comment: @joseph4tw Last column will NOT (NEVER) have carriage return or even could be made to NEVER have by adding say a numeric field in the end. This is a given.

Comment: @momobo I will welcome suggestions in 2 separate ways.. BOTH REQUIRED... 1) best and easy way to write the pre-process to once and for all settle the case for any future cases with files like this.. i am familiar with python and vba 2) how to fix the source data in sql server 2015 with multiline fields so that not to get in this mess for any new data... Pls make suggestions for both requirements.

Comment: as i read from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389796/how-to-make-excel-save-a-file-as-text-with-support-for-unicode-and-support-for?rq=1 only if the fields are having " quotes around the field.. then it splits very nicely... important is to click "shift and open" in the file dialog as mentioned there.. Anyway.. for above  Item 2.. it will help if i can export from sql server 2015 with quotes around the fields.... For Item 1 in above comment... will be interested to see how the quotes can be added now easily.. or any other short cuts.

Comment: @joseph4tw I have added additional comments to my question based on what I have read so far... May be someone can find a smart quick solution and an explanation in 2 parts. 1) How to fix the existing file 2) How to fix the data source in SQL Server 2015 for future.

Comment: Preprocessing would be very convenient with python (I assume is like perl that I know) but would conflict be maybe difficult for your users (they should activate an external program, I guess). Maybe it is better working direct in Excel or Access with VBA. Even better would be working with the exporting program in the DB to have a file where the record delimiter (CR) is not present in the data. An other option is enough to run a program to substitute CR in the original data with another less intrusive character (say '|' for example). You should see what you have available.

Comment: @momobo i have provided my own solution without any code involved... Wish someone can improve it further for the leading 0 issue and "shift + open"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. If you can guarantee the last column will never have a carriage return, then this should work ok.

What this does is read the text file in VBA and brings it into the workbook. You have to specify how many fields to expect (in the test scenario, 4). This is so it can keep track of when it's ready to start a new row.

It's a little confusing because of the carriage returns, but step through the code and I think you'll be able to figure it out. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
Option Explicit

Const fieldCount = 4

Sub import()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim fileNumber As Integer
    Dim data As String
    Dim curCol As Long, curRow As Long
    Dim dataCols As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim hasCarriageReturn As Boolean

    fileNumber = FreeFile()
    Open "C:\test.txt" For Input As #fileNumber
    curCol = 1
    curRow = 1
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    While Not EOF(fileNumber)
        ' if we reached the "correct" last column, then move to next row
        If (curCol > fieldCount) Then
            curCol = 1
            curRow = curRow + 1
            hasCarriageReturn = False
        End If

        Line Input #fileNumber, data
        arr = Split(data, vbTab)
        dataCols = UBound(arr)



        If (dataCols = fieldCount - 1) Then
            ' full row has no carriage returns
            hasCarriageReturn = False

            For i = 0 To dataCols
                sh.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value = arr(i)
                curCol = curCol + 1
            Next

        ElseIf (dataCols = 0 And hasCarriageReturn = True) Then
            ' if there is only 1 value in the row, append it to the current column
            sh.Cells(curRow, curCol - 1).Formula = sh.Cells(curRow, curCol - 1).Formula & Chr(10) & arr(0)

        ElseIf (dataCols = 0 And hasCarriageReturn = False) Then
            ' carriage return begins in the first field
            sh.Cells(curRow, curCol).Formula = sh.Cells(curRow, curCol).Formula & Chr(10) & arr(0)
            curCol = curCol + 1
            hasCarriageReturn = True

        ElseIf (hasCarriageReturn) Then
            ' append first item to field 3, then rest goes in other columns
            sh.Cells(curRow, curCol - 1).Formula = sh.Cells(curRow, curCol - 1).Formula & Chr(10) & arr(0)
            For i = 1 To dataCols
                sh.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value = arr(i)
                curCol = curCol + 1
            Next

            hasCarriageReturn = False

        Else
            ' process row and note that it has carriage returns
            For i = 0 To dataCols
                sh.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value = arr(i)
                curCol = curCol + 1
            Next

            hasCarriageReturn = True
        End If

    Wend

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: please note.. this will not work.. the original text file how it looks has been shown already on top... and your method will not work on that file. as soon as i import the file in excel... the line which says "Field 3.2" will be on a separate row by itself (Row 2 Column A).

Comment: @ihightower my apologies, I missed that detail. Let me see if I can figure something out.

Comment: i have added a new answer myself (without code).. can you pls check and comment on it on improving the part of leading 0. I will test your answer tomorrow at work. Thank you so much.

Comment: code works great and i have accepted your answer. wish i can do it without writing any code and my solution (or something similar) may be the only option without writing any code. Thank you.

Comment: @ihightower I agree that it should be fixed at the source. It's a tough situation you're in, though, and sometimes you have to do things like this, unfortunately. Luckily, though, we have found a workaround :)

Answer (score 2):

for the time being what i did was.. used gvim (same like 'vi') and replaced all

`\t` with `"\t"` *(this is to have the fields wrapped in quotes..*.then.. e.g. `:%s/\t/"\t"/g`

`\r\n` with `"\r` *(this is to have the real end of line to have a quote in the end..*. then e.g. `:%s/\r\n/"\r/g`

line start `^20` with `^"20` *(this is for beginning of line first field in quotes... the line starts with 2013... so replacing with with "2013...)* e.g. `:%s/^2013/"2013/g`

saved the file.. as file.txt

Open Excel

Select the File... and hold shift and click "open" (courtesy of: [Import multiline csv files into Excel internationally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443204/import-multiline-csv-files-into-excel-internationally?rq=1))

All fields are nicely imported (in General Format) and multilines are processed correctly and put in correct fields.

This is truly wonderful... **However with 1 caveat.**

Some of the fields are text but with leading 0s.. e.g. `'000327511'` or `'032'`.. and i wanted the leading zero intact.. without excel converting to number. I can't preserve the leading 0 using the "shift + open" method.

If I use the normal text import wizard... then the multiline cannot be made to work.. catch 22 situation. Pity!!!

However.. this is a nice temporary solution until someone can find a permanent fix all one.
No code involved at all... just a few typing to replace with vi and click.. click..

Wish someone can improve this method slightly.

Comment: if you can do some sort of grep for the number, you can try adding an additional apostrophe `'` at the front of the number. Excel might realize to format that in plain text, rather than a number.

Comment: I'd like to clarify this a little based on what I found. The file to be imported must have TXT extension, not CSV. The file should have CRLF line endings. There must be CRLF inserted between fields, not just CR as is implied by ihightower. So a line of text looks like '"Field 1"<TAB>"Field 2"<TAB>"Line1Field 3.1<CR><LF>Field 3.2<CR><LF>Field 3.3"<TAB>"Field 4"<CR><LF>'

Comment: Also, after the import Excel shows each row as the same size -- it doesn't autosize the multiple line rows - easy enough to fix, it just looks wrong at first.

Answer (score 0):

Import to Libre Office Calc. Libre Office Calc does not interpret line breaks in between two tabs as a next row command. The content after line break will appear in the next line within the same cell. Save the spreadsheet as ms excel xls/xlsx format.
Ignore the warning that pops up before it is saved at your own risk and/or proof-read the same spreadsheet after import. During the proof read make sure you're using Excel.

Comment: Actually in version 5, line breaks between delimiters do break to the next row.  I can't see an option to stop this behaviour.